# When I'm doing this query I'm getting NULL values. Why?

Tags: oracle, null, sum

I have a table called `fact_trip` which has a column as `fare_final` and I want to find the difference between values.

```
SQL> desc fact_trip
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 TRIP_UUID                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 DATESTR                                            DATE
 PRODUCT_TYPE_NAME                                  VARCHAR2(20)
 CITY_ID                                            NUMBER
 DRIVER_UUID                                        VARCHAR2(50)
 IS_COMPLETED                                       VARCHAR2(10)
 ETA                                                NUMBER
 ATA                                                NUMBER
 UFP_FARE                                           NUMBER(4,2)
 FARE_FINAL                                         NUMBER(4,2)
```

So when I do this I'm getting NULL as output:

```
SQL>  select sum(fare_final) from fact_trip where to_char(datestr, 'W')=1 - (select sum(fare_final) from fact_trip where to_char(datestr, 'W')=2);

SUM(FARE_FINAL)
---------------
```

I even tried doing those select queries individually like this:

```
SQL> select sum(fare_final) from fact_trip where to_char(datestr, 'W')=1;

SUM(FARE_FINAL)
---------------
         1821.6

SQL> select sum(fare_final) from fact_trip where to_char(datestr, 'W')=2;

SUM(FARE_FINAL)
---------------
             67
```

Which is of course fetching result. But then when I run those queries for what I want a difference of them, it's showing NULL. Like I want difference of them `(1821.6 - 67)`.
Can anybody tell what's wrong in it?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is not a worksheet, where you may evaluate any expression. You cannot use an [*expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/About-SQL-Expressions.html#GUID-68789A5C-B142-496F-ADEE-837F75F95B2B) as a SQL command: you have to either`select` an expression `from` something, or calculate it in PL/SQL block.

You want to calculate the difference, so you *assumed* your code is: `subquery - subquery`. But because of described above this is not syntactically correct command, and parser tries to find a parse tree which is syntactically correct. And it actually finds one:

```
select sum(fare_final)
from fact_trip
where to_char(datestr, 'W') = (
  1 - (
    select sum(fare_final)
    from fact_trip
    where to_char(datestr, 'W') = 2
  )
)
```

Of course, such week doesn't exist and you get `null` as a result.

To turn your code into a correct command, the simplest way is to `select` the *expression* from a `dual` table with appropriate brackets to specify calculation precedence:

```
select
  (select sum(fare_final) from fact_trip where to_char(datestr, 'W')='1')
  - (select sum(fare_final) from fact_trip where to_char(datestr, 'W')='2') as res
from dual
```

But more performant and set-based approach would be:

```
select
  sum(
    case to_char(datestr, 'W')
      when '1' then 1
      when '2' then -1
    end * fare_final
  ) as res
from fact_trip
where to_char(datestr, 'W') in ('1', '2')
```

Below is the sample code with results of all that was described above:

> ```
> select * from t
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | VAL
> -: | --:
>  1 |   3
>  2 |   6
>  3 |   9
> ```

> ```
> select sum(val)
> from t
> where id = 1 - (
>   select sum(val)
>   from t
>   where id = 2
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> | SUM(VAL) |
> | -------: |
> |     null |
> ```

> ```
> select
>   (
> (select sum(val)
> from t
> where id = 1) - (
>   select sum(val)
>   from t
>   where id = 2
> )
>   ) as q
> from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> |  Q |
> | -: |
> | -3 |
> ```

> ```
> select
>   sum(
>     case id
>      when 1 then 1
>      when 2 then -1
>     end * val
>   ) as res
> from t
> where id in (1, 2)
> ```
>
> ```
> | RES |
> | --: |
> |  -3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=aa5207ea46c7c6b2aa3f2ce82499e76c)*

Comment: Thank you! It actually helped me. And I gained some knowledge too!

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
SELECT SUM (
          CASE
             WHEN TO_CHAR (datestr, 'W') = 1 THEN  fare_final
             WHEN TO_CHAR (datestr, 'W') = 2 THEN -fare_final
          END)
  FROM fact_trip;
```

---

I don't have your table so I'll illustrate it on Scott's EMP, computing the *total* for analysts and clerks:

```
SQL>   SELECT job, sal FROM emp ORDER BY job;

JOB              SAL
--------- ----------
ANALYST         3000  --> total for analysts is 6000
ANALYST         3000
CLERK           1300  --> total for clerks   is 4150
CLERK            950
CLERK            800  --> difference: 6000 - 4150 = 1850
CLERK           1100
MANAGER         2850
MANAGER         2975
MANAGER         2450
PRESIDENT       5000
SALESMAN        1500
SALESMAN        1250
SALESMAN        1250
SALESMAN        1600

14 rows selected.

SQL> SELECT SUM (
  2            CASE WHEN job = 'ANALYST' THEN  sal
  3                 WHEN job = 'CLERK'   THEN -sal
  4            END) total
  5    FROM emp;

     TOTAL
----------
      1850

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your effort. I gained some knowledge here!